# Python enumerate isn't plotting the right matplotlib figures?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, enumerate

I'm trying to simulate the following system of chemical reactions:

```
1S + 0T + 0U --> 0S + 0T + 0U
2S + 0T + 0U --> 0S + 1T + 0U 
0S + 1T + 0U --> 2S + 0T + 0U
0S + 1T + 0U --> 0S + 0T + 1U
```

The ratios between the reactants and products are expressed in the following arrays:

```
LHS = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]) <-- ratio between the reactants
RHS = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]) <-- ratio between the reactants
```

The change in ratio after each reaction is fired is stored in this array:

```
state_change_array = np.asarray(RHS - LHS)
```

I have the following discrete molecule numbers for the three reactants, S, T, U in the system at the start of the simulation respectively:

```
popul_num = np.array([1.0E5, 0, 0])
```

The rate of each respective reaction is stored in the following array:

```
stoch_rate = np.array([1.0, 0.002, 0.5, 0.04])
```

I have written the following code to simulate the system and store the new numbers for the calculated popul_num

```
def propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate):
propensity = np.zeros(len(LHS))
for row in range(len(LHS)):
        a = stoch_rate[row]     # type = numpy.float64
        for i in range(len(popul_num)):
            if (popul_num[i] >= LHS[row, i]):      
                binom_rxn = binom(popul_num[i], LHS[row, i])
                a = a*binom_rxn
            else:
                a = 0
                break
        propensity[row] = a     # type = numpy.ndarray
return propensity

popul_num_all = [popul_num]
propensity = np.zeros(len(LHS))

while tao < tmax:
    propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)
    a0 = (sum(propensity))
    if a0 == 0.0:
        break
    t = np.random.exponential(1/a0)
    rxn_probability = propensity / a0   
    num_rxn = np.arange(rxn_probability.size)       
    if tao + t > tmax:
        tao = tmax
        break
    j = stats.rv_discrete(values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs() 
    tao = tao + t
    popul_num = popul_num + np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j]))   
    print("Population numbers:\n", popul_num)
    print("Simulation time:\n", t, tao)
    popul_num_all.append(popul_num)

popul_num_all = np.array(popul_num_all)
```

Where tmax is the maximum time the system should simulate up to = 20.0, and tao is the start time, 0.

I've then got the following to plot the changing numbers of each species in the system:

```
for i, label in enumerate(['S', 'T', 'U']):
    plt.plot(popul_num_all[i], label=label) 
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The code plotting code has worked for a different simulation that ran, but in this simulation it shows all three species decreasing at the same rate (see graph below), which isn't what I want.
I've had a play around with the indexing and the rates but still cant seem to get it quite right, any suggestions?

I've got the numpy, scipy and matplotlib imports in by the way

[image]

Comment: Figured it out, Dont worry!

Comment: Are you planning to self-answer?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was on this line:

```
plt.plot(popul_num_all[i], label=label)
```

popul_num_all is a big 2D array, so I think the problem was something to do with indexing both dimensions of the axes. I had to add in:

```
plt.plot(popul_num_all[:, i], label=label)
```

To make it work for more than one dimension.